# What is the license of the code uploaded to Screeps?

Tags: screeps

Screeps requires users to input code in order to play. A copy of this code is then sent to Screeps server so that they can provide the game service.

**Under what terms is the code provided by the user?** Is it only for the purposes of running the game? Or is it an implicit full license to do anything? Is the user still the sole owner of the code he submits?

[Screeps Terms of Service](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203833952-Terms-of-Service) is rather terse and says nothing specifically on the matter. The closest we get is this:

> You acknowledge and agree that you have no interest, monetary or otherwise, in any feature or content contained in the Game.

Since user-generated content is still content, it can be argued that by playing Screeps, you in fact forfeit all ownership of everything you upload. Is that interpretation correct?

I understand they need *some* rights to run the game. I also understand the game encourages open sourcing your code. But most similar services clearly spell out the rules. Github TOS section on User-Generated Content is actually longer than the entire Screeps license. I think asking for clarification is only fair here.

Answer (score 2):

The screeps developers claim no copyright over any of the code you upload.

In most countries you must explicitly grant a copyright ownership change- it's not something that can happen automatically, and at a bare minimum you must agree to terms to do this. Since there are no terms or requirements to do this in any of the screeps documentation then this isn't the case.

A further factor is that the code is now [open source under the ISC license](https://github.com/screeps/engine/blob/master/LICENSE.txt), which is a permissive license.

Comment: The license of the game itself makes no difference here, just like the license of node.js isn't important, or the license of the OS it's installed on. It's just a service used to run your code, and it being proprietary or open source changes nothing.

Comment: Are you able to point out some specific laws or examples that prove your point? I pointed out a part of TOS that _might_ be construed to imply copyright transfer. Can you address that?

There's also the matter of license to use code, separate from copyright. And the service _does_ use user code. They couldn't run the game otherwise.

Comment: tell that to Activision Blizzard. Im sure they would love you on their Warcraft 3 spin team